# How to use grid in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a assignment.

I want to create a grid with list of friends with their name and photo add search bar on top of it whenever you type their name, it should filter and show only that by default it should show all.

Comment: No one is going to do your assignment for you. You should start the assignment, and if you have a specific question about code you've written, you can ask here.

Comment: [Duplicate of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33762363/472495) - downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easy achieved using JQuery and a 3rd party javascript library called "Datatables".
Basically you only need to create an HTML table with all the names and photos, then add JQuery and Datatbles libraries to your HTML and initialize it.

On this link: 
https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html 
you will find the most basic code example to configure datatables.

As comment, this solution will indeed give you the results you look for, but if this is a homework maybe your professor is expecting to you to code this functionality from scratch and not using 3rd party libraries.

Regards.